# Auto-fill input with data from Mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hi, I am using a JQuery script to fill 3 fields on my form when an ID is selected. My script pulls data from 3 different PHP files and it is making my script run slowly. I would like to know if there is a way to compile all of my PHP files into 1 file to make my script more convenient.

script

```
function updatefrm($name, $qty1, $price, $plink) {
var name = $("#" + $name).val();
if ($.trim(name) !='') {
    $.post('../action/subs/name2.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
        $("#" + $qty1).val(data);       
});
    $.post('../action/subs/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
        $("#" + $price).val(data);  
});

    $.post('../action/subs/name3.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
        $('#cimage').attr('src', '../components/mijoshop/opencart/image  /'+data);      
});

}
}
```

name.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {

require '../db/connect6.php';

$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `product`.`price` 
FROM `shop_product`
WHERE  `shop_product`.`product_id` = '".  mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']))."'
    ");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query)!==0)? mysql_result($query,0,`price`):'price not  found';

}

?>
```

name1.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {

require '../db/connect6.php';

$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `product`.`product_id` 
FROM `shop_product`
WHERE  `shop_product`.`product_id` = '".     mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']))."'
    ");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query)!==0)? mysql_result($query,0,`product_id`):'price not found';

}

?>
```

name2.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {

require '../db/connect6.php';

$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `product`.`image` 
FROM `shop_product`
WHERE  `shop_product`.`product_id` = '".       mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']))."'
    ");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query)!==0)? mysql_result($query,0,`image`):'price not  found';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your name.php script so that it does the following:

```
<?php
// empty will do isset too, so you get two for the price of one!
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    require '../db/connect6.php';

    $safe_name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));

    $query = mysql_query("
        SELECT price, product_id, image
        FROM `shop_product`
        WHERE  `shop_product`.`product_id` = '". $safe_name ."'
        LIMIT 1
    ");

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        json($row);
    } else {
        json(null);
    }
}

function json ($array) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($array);
}

?>
```

Then change your javascript to:

```
if ($.trim(name) !='') {
    $.post('../action/subs/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
        $("#" + $qty1).val(data['qty']);
        $("#" + $price).val(data['price']);
        $("#cimage").attr('src', '../components/mijoshop/opencart/image/'+data['image']);
    });
}
```

Comment: @user3383794 no problems!

Answer (score 0):

You should request all your mysql data with one query using LIMIT 1, (now you're looping through all rows in your database 3 times. Then send the data as json to your jquery before you populate your fields.

You can google for "jquery json php" to read more about it.

Something like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT product_id,price,image FROM shop_product WHERE product_id = $id LIMTI 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo json_encode(array('id' => "$row['product_id']", 'price' => "$row['price']", 'image' => "$row['image']"));
}
```